# Definition of irreducible element of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I found in my notes the following definition:

Let $r\neq 0$, $r$ non-invertible.

$r\in R$ is called irreducible iff $r=a\cdot b$ with $a,b\in R$ then either $a\in U(R)$ or $b\in U(R)$.

Why does this stand? I haven't understood that... Could you explain it to me?

Comment: What do you not understand? It is the way one often defines prime numbers for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being in $U(R)$ is the natural analogy of being $1$.  In $\mathbb{N}$, $1$ is the only unit.  In $\mathbb{Z}$, there are two; $\pm 1$.  In $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ there are four; $\pm 1$ and $\pm i$.  In $F[t]$, each constant polynomial is a unit.

Note that for  $p\in\mathbb{Z}$, $p$ is called prime if whenever $p=a\cdot b$, we must have $a=\pm 1$ or $b=\pm 1$.

Comment: Ah ok... I understood it now!! Thank you very much!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

### Example:

$5$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Z$, because the only way to write $5$ as $a\cdot b$ is having one of $a$ or $b$ to be $\pm 1$, i.e. a unit of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Ah ok... I understood it now!! Thank you very much!! :-)